# deleting collapsed code section in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Collapsing code sections is nice. But everytime I select the collapsed part in the editor and cut/delete it the selection expands and I have to find the start/end manually in the expanded code.

Is there an easier way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your cursor is inside the element you can use `Select Enclosing Element` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. You may need to press it a few times, depending how many levels of enclosing elements there are (blocks like loops).

You may use a desktop environment that thinks it is a good idea to define a few hundred shortcuts that you will never use but that override all your application shortcuts (Ubuntu Unity). In this case you may need to change your desktop environment (by far the most painless way to solve this problem).

Comment: actually that quite handy to also check the enclosing scope... By the way, I am sorry but I am not really sure if I understood your second paragraph. Are you suggesting to change the editor?

Comment: No, sorry, that was just a rant against Ubuntu Unity, a Linux graphical user interface. While in general I can live with it (I use desktop environments for starting applications so I don't see them for long) this particular one combines the worst of everything when it comes to keyboard shortcuts (dozens or more, much too much; no system; not configurable by default; overriding application shortcuts). In short you can't use applications like Eclipse or Blender effectively when using it. If you use Windows or any other desktop this doesn't affect you. Sorry, that just annoyed me today.

Answer (score 0):

Using Neon

1. Collapse the code
2. Double click the collapsed code
3. Hit ctrl-x or the Delete key.

Hitting Backspace or the Enter key still just expands the collapsed code